# generate jqgrid using model id / pass id to controller's post method to generate jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I want to know how to generate jqgrid by passing Id to controller's post method ? Is there any postdata kind of attribute available in jqgrid? Please give me detailed example to generate jqgrid based on perticular id and how to get this Id in controller's post method?

Let me give some more clarification...

Here my controller method which returns View :

```
public ActionResult Index1(int Id)
        {
            ViewBag.Id = Id;
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Now this index view is here :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#AssetTable").jqGrid({
            url: '/Controller/List',
            mtype: 'POST',
            datatype: "json",
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows", //array containing actual data
                page: "page", //current page
                total: "total", //total pages for the queryd
                records: "records", //total number of records
                repeatitems: false,
                id: "ID" //index of the column with the PK in it
            },
            colNames: ['ID', 'Dedicated', 'Post Of'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', width: 150, formatter: myLinkFormatter },
                { name: 'Dedicated', width: 300},
                { name: 'PostOf', width: 300 }


            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 15, 20],
            pager: '#AssetTablePager',
            sortname: 'Dedicated',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Armories",
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto",
            altRows: true,
            altclass: 'OddGridRow'
    });
```

This is my controller's post method which generate jqgrid **Here I want Id as parameter because i want to generate grid based on this id** :

```
public override JsonResult List(int? page, int? rows, string sidx, string sord, bool _search, string searchField, string searchOper, string searchString)
    {
        var _db = new AOAEntities();
        // Create the Repository and get the Model
        List<vendor> _data = new VendorRepository().GetList();

        //load the Model in to the ViewModel

        List<VendorVM> _vendors = _data.Select(x => new VendorVM
        {
            ID = x.id_vendor,
            Name = x.nm_vendor.Trim(),
            DefaultObjectCode = x.object_codes == null ? "" : x.object_codes.ds_code.Trim() + "-" + x.object_codes.ds_description.Trim(),
            AddressLine1 = x.ds_address_line1.Trim(),

            City = x.ds_city.Trim(),

            Phone = x.ds_phone.Trim()




        }).ToList();

        int _page = page ?? 1;
        int _rows = rows ?? 1;

        if (_search)
        {
            _vendors = _vendors.AsQueryable().Where(searchField, searchString, searchOper).ToList();
        }

        var sortedAssets = _vendors.AsQueryable().SortBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", sidx, sord));

        sortedAssets = sortedAssets.Skip((_page - 1) * _rows).Take(_rows);
        var pagedAssets = (_vendors.Count / rows) + (_vendors.Count % rows == 0 ? 0 : 1);

        var results = new
        {
            total = pagedAssets, //number of pages
            page = page, //current page
            records = _vendors.Count(), //total items
            rows = sortedAssets
        };

        return Json(results);
    }
```

**My question is how to get id in this method (public override JsonResult List)**

Comment: please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you need. Which id you mean (id of some row, id of the grid, id of row of master grid to fill the content of the second grid etc.)? Do you have some problem in *filling* the grid or in *editing* of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url.Action helper include the id parameter. The View:

```
...
url: $("#GetQueueGridAction").data("url"),
...

<div id="GetQueueGridAction" data-url="@Url.Action("GetAction", "Controller", new { id = ViewBag.Id })"></div>
```

Then in the controller method signature:

```
public JsonResult GetQueue(int id, string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
```